# Detect GLSL vs GLSL ES support in OpenGL 1.x

Tags: opengl, glsl, glsles

I'm writing for using GLSL and shader objects in OpenGL versions before Core 2.0.  My source code detects that the OpenGL version is below 2.0 and then checks for GL_ARB_shading_language_100 support.  If it is supported then it assumes GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, and GL_ARB_fragment_shader are supported.

I've noticed that my assumption that this means GLSL 1 is supported is wrong because GLSL ES 1.2 is supported and all my shader source code fails to compile (lack of 3D texture support).  glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION_ARB) is unhelpful (returns 1.20) and isn't documented to be helpful.

Is there a way to detect if GLSL ES is supported through extensions?

Comment: The `autotools` system (`autoconf` and `automake`) solved this problem long ago.  Instead of version detection, they attempt to compile little snippets that exercise the feature in question.  GLSL compilation failure can be detected, so I think you could use the same approach.

Comment: I am confused about that version number. There is no `GLSL ES 1.2`, only `1.0`, `3.0`, and `3.1` (for OpenGL ES versions `2.0`, `3.0`, and `3.1` respectively). How do you know that `GLSL ES 1.2` is supported?